# The variable B is unbound in Lisp

Tags: lisp, scope

sorry for my poor english:)
I have a problem with lisp. i type code here http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html to **sbcl**

```
* (define a 3)

; in: DEFINE A
;     (DEFINE A 3)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: A
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: DEFINE
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     DEFINE
;   Undefined variable:
;     A
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread #<THREAD
                                               "initial thread" RUNNING
                                                {10029211E1}>:
The variable A is unbound.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
 0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

some one give me a help?

Comment: SICP uses Scheme, one Lisp dialect.  SBCL implements Common Lisp, another Lisp dialect.  I think you need to use a Scheme implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a function with DEFUN:

```
(defun a () 3)
```

In your case you're trying to call the function DEFINE with an argument A... which is of course undefined.

More generally, you supply the parameters to a function [like this](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html):

```
(defun param-taking-fun (a b)
  (+ a b))
```

Note that Scheme is a 1-lisp (same namespace for functions and variables) while SBCL, like all Common Lisp implementations, is a 2-lisp (different namespaces for functions and variables).

Thus in Scheme `(define foo 3)` defines a constant while `(define foo (lambda () 3))` defines a constant function. In Common Lisp [one way](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_defconstant.html) to define a constant is

```
(defconstant foo 3)
```

Comment: Serves me right for working from memory. The `()` indicates the function takes no parameters.

Comment: resolved! caused of i use **sbcl**, but write Scheme code,:P,Thanks,

Comment: Yes, I'd assumed you'd _intended_ to translate the Scheme to Common Lisp! Glad I could help, at least.

Comment: Big Thanks :),[like this](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html)link is very useful for me